# Horizontal Scrolling in DIV array

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make a horizontal scrolling that can go to the nearest div when is in any place of the whole container, let me explain, the pager is fixed and can handle to go next or prev section, from the begining any scroller can do that but in my case the horizontal scrollbar will be active, so anyone can move around.
What Im trying to make is that the pager "knows" ,by making an array of divs, what section is viewing the user (commonly the one more closest to the center) and if is clicked prev or next it goes to the prev or next div (is it possible?).

I hope I explined my idea.

I'll appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Here is the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/viciosogb/pqEfj/

Im Using Jquery 1.7.1 and scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();

    var prev = $(this).not('.next').attr('href');


    if($(this).attr('class') == 'next'){ 

    $(this).parent().animate({"margin-left":"-="+$(this).parent().outerWidth()+"px"},800);
    }else{
    $(prev).animate({"margin-left":"+="+$(prev).outerWidth()+"px"},800);
    }                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Wrapper around the `div.section`:

```
.wrap {
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So it should look like:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="seccion" class="section">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :) All the best! :)